# Bash Sed (Regex) - Matching n-th occurence of pattern, checking if exists

Tags: regex, bash, sed

### These are string variables to match from:

```
str1='V 12345678Z 12345678N 05 sometext some/t2/text'
str2='V 12345678Z 05 sometext some/t2/text'
```

...where `12345678Z` and `12345678N` can be a random 8-digit number and a random capital letter

### Goal:

Find if a **second pattern** of `[0-9]{8}[A-Z]` **exists** in text like `$str1` or `$str2`. If so, return it to `$match`

### 1) Second occurence exists:

```
match=$(echo $str1 | sed -r 's/.*([0-9]{8}[A-Z]){1}.*/\1/')
```

Returns first occurence "`12345678Z`"

```
match=$(echo $str1 | sed -r 's/.*([0-9]{8}[A-Z]){2}.*/\1/')
```

Returns second occurence "`12345678N`" and everything works well.

### 2) Second occurence doesn't exist:

```
match=$(echo $str2 | sed -r 's/.*([0-9]{8}[A-Z]){2}.*/\1/')
```

It returns the whole string "`V 12345678Z 05 sometext some/t2/text`" and this is misinterpreted by further code.

**How to make it to return `false` or `null` or `-1` if second occurence doesn't exist instead of the full string?**

Do I really need to make a check if `$match != $str2` as  a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash:

```
str1='V 12345678Z 12345678N 05 sometext some/t2/text'

if [[ $str1 =~ [0-9]{8}[A-Z]\ ([0-9]{8}[A-Z]) ]]; then
  match="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else 
  match="false"
fi
echo "$match"
```

Output:

```
12345678N
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a great solution! I used it with a little change for more flexibility:
`if [[ $str1 =~ [0-9]{8}[A-Z].*([0-9]{8}[A-Z]) ]]; then`

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the `-n` sed flag and add a `p` command to only print matching strings.

You can then test `$match` value and return what your want if it's empty:

```
$ str2='V 123456781234Z 05 sometext some/t2/text'    
$ match=$(sed -nr 's/.*([0-9]{12}[A-Z] *){2}.*/\1/p' <<< "$str2")
$ [[ -n "$match" ]] && echo "$match" || echo "No match"
No match
```

---

<sub>Note: I updated your sample variable values to match the `[0-9]{12}` pattern.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! This would also work, however I chose to go with Cyrus solution.